# How to append the telephone number to the country code in angular 5 with primeng

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng, angular-reactive-forms, ngxs

Currently I'm working on a project using  Angular 5 with primeng. I'm trying to append the country which coming from a dropdown to the phone number in a reactive form. I'm having a problem when I select a country code from a dropdown It doesn't append to the telephone number which I do have to pass the value.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    phoneNumber: new FormControl('')
  })

  onSubmit(phoneValue){
    console.log(phoneValue)
  }

  onCountryChange(event){
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(profileForm.value)">
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-xs-12 ui-sm-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-4 responsiveForIpad">
      <div class="ui-g passengerMainDetails">
             <div class="ui-g-12 ui-xs-12 ui-sm-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-12">
                   <label> Contact Number *</label>
              </div>
       <div class="ui-g-12 ui-xs-12 ui-sm-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-12">
          <input type="text" formControlName="phoneNumber" ng2TelInput  (countryChange)="onCountryChange($event)" placeholder="Please Enter the Phone number here"/>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a valid Form Control that is passed to the `ng2TelInput` while you have `phoneName` in you TS and `MobileNo` in your HTML.

After that, the value will be binded to the from control and can be accessed when submitting using `this.profileForm.get('phoneNumber').value`. This will return an object which you can get the number using the `internationalNumber` if you want the formatting with the `+` and spaces, or using the `number` / `nationalNumber` if you need it without the formatting.

For that, you won't really need the `onCountryChange` emitter as we will get the number when submitting (Except if you need the listener for something else).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    phoneNumber: new FormControl('')
  });

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.phoneForm.get('phone').value.internationalNumber);
  }
}
```

---

```html
 <form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(profileForm.value)">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-xs-12 ui-sm-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-4 responsiveForIpad">
          <div class="ui-g passengerMainDetails">
                 <div class="ui-g-12 ui-xs-12 ui-sm-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-12">
                       <label> Contact Number *</label>
                  </div>
           <div class="ui-g-12 ui-xs-12 ui-sm-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-12">
              <input type="text" formControlName="phoneNumber" ng2TelInput placeholder="Please Enter the Phone number here"/>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </form>
```